# Unit Vector Property Proof

Tags: vectors

I'm trying to prove that if $\textbf{u}$ and $\textbf{v}$ are unit vectors and $\theta$ is the angle between them, $||\textbf{u}-\textbf{v}||=2\sin(\frac{1}{2}\theta)$. The only thing I've come up with is that, from the law of cosines, $||\textbf{u}-\textbf{v}||=\sqrt{2(1-\cos(\theta)}$. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This follows almost immediatly I would say from the identity that $\cos{2x} = 1 - 2\sin^2{x}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the double angle identity $\cos(2x) = 1 - 2\sin^2(x)$ with $x = \frac{1}{2}\theta$ to obtain $\cos(\theta) = 1 - 2\sin^2(\frac{1}{2}\theta)$. Thus $$2\sin^2\left(\frac{1}{2}\theta\right) = 1 - \cos(\theta),$$

which implies

$$\sqrt{2(1 - \cos(\theta))} = \sqrt{4\sin^2\left(\frac{1}{2}\theta\right)} = 2\sin\left(\frac{1}{2}\theta\right).$$